# return an array from a function multiple times and deallocate the memory in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, free

I've been trying to wrap my head around pointers in C now for a while but I seem to be stuck on a problem that has to do with memory. I'm working on a function that returns an array from another function multiple times and then should deallocate the array in the end. Returning the array once works just fine but if I try to return it more then once the program is aborted and I get a segmentation error. The code of this function is

```
double func(int n, int max, int s){
    int i;
    int *p;
    int *q;
    double diff_t;
    //start timer
    time_t start_t, end_t;
    time(&start_t);
    //generate the arrays and search for s
    for(i=0;i<100;++i){
            p=initarray(n,max);
            q=sort(n,p);
            search(s,n,q);
    }
    //calculate elapsed time
    time(&end_t);
    diff_t=difftime(end_t,start_t);
    //deallocate array
    free(p);
    return(diff_t);
}
```

and the other functions used within this function are

```
int *initarray(int n, int max){
    //allocate memory for the array
    int *arr=malloc(n);

    //initialize an array
    ....

    //return the array
    return(arr);
}


int *sort(int n, int *arr){
    //sort the array
    ...

    //return the array
    return(arr);
}


int search(int i, int n, int *arr){
    int j;
    int index;
    //search the array for i
    ...
    //return the index of i in the array        
    return(index);
}
```

I then call func in the main function as

```
func(2000,10000,10)
```

Also whenever I try to deallocate the array with free(p), for example, the program is aborted and returns a double free or corruption error. So I basically have two problems: I can't get my function to return the array more than once and I'm not able to deallocate the array in the end. I've searched the internet high and low but could get nothing to work, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `int *arr=malloc(n);` --> `int *arr=malloc(n * sizeof(int));`. Also You have memory leaks.

Comment: Aside: there is a general convention that people expect `foo_t` to be a type, not a variable. You might reconsider your naming scheme for time-holding variables; e.g. maybe `t_end` instead, or `end_time`.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: The only obvious problem evident in code you have shown is that `malloc()` may be allocating insufficient memory, as noted by BLUEPIXY. Otherwise, if your code is exiting with a "segmentation error", some code you haven't shown is exhibiting undefined behaviour.   The code you have not shown, such as the bodies of functions `initarray()`, `sort()`, and `search()`, or of the calling `main()` will be the culprits.    Since you are not providing an MCVE, I am voting to close the question due to being unclear.

Comment: I have fixed the allocation with malloc() and it appears to be working now, thanks!!

Comment: @Peter Or, instead of VTCing as unclear because of the lack of MCVE, VTC for the specific reason that says "questions must have an MCVE".

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is simple. You are allocating memory multiple times. but you are freeing the memory only once. ie: the last memory block allocated. Just move the free(p) statement inside your for loop.

```
for(i=0;i<100;++i)
{
        p=initarray(n,max);
        q=sort(n,p);
        search(s,n,q);
        //deallocate array
        free(p);
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't fix a memory corruption error, only a memory leak. But that's not what the question is about.